# Redirect everything after /

Tags: redirect

> http://example.com/product/12312

I want to redirect everything after the /, in this case the "12312", to the site's root.

> http://example.com/

I tried playing with .htaccess, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What web server are you working on? What did you "try playing with" and how did it not meet your expectations? Did you get any errors? What behavior did you observe?

Comment: I'm using 000webhost web host.The thing about 000webhost, is that whenever there's an error it redirects you to their homepage with title error, and not showing the error..